# Python display large collection of images side by side

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I have a list of tuples in python of about 400 elements. The first and second elements of the tuple are numpy arrays and the third element is a string, which should be the title of the two.
What I need to do is display the images side by side both having the same title.
The images are 512x512 pixels but resizing is an option as long as the information in the resulted image will not be affected by much. This is what I currently have.

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(len(data), 2)
for idx, (target, output, title) in enumerate(data):
    axarr[idx, 0].imshow(target)
    axarr[idx, 1].imshow(output)
    axarr[idx, 0].set_title(f"TARGET: {title}")
    axarr[idx, 1].set_title(f"OUTPUT: {title}")
plt.show()
```

The problem with this is that it just plots the title one on top of the other, no images.[image]

Comment: All those axes spines and ticks overlap, such that you end up with a black mess. I'd suggest you first plot only two datasets. Then think about if plotting 400 makes much sense.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You're right, that is exactly what is happening. I managed to plot a grid of 2x2 and it works but I was looking for an option where I would have them all in a scrollable list or smth. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, in principle you can increase the figure height to some huge number to have them all fit, but I'm really not sure if it makes sense to create an image of 40000 pixels in height.